# adding loading status in jquery toogle

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have a link when a user clicks the content from other page will be loaded. I am using jquery it works fine, but I want to show loading status in case it takes time to load. It will be better if user see something is going on, so I want when he click the link it shows

" **please wait..**"

status until the content fully loaded.

here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){       

        $('#view').toggle(function(){
            var href=$(this).attr('href');
            $('#load').hide().fadeIn().load(href);
            $('#view').text('Hide');
            return false;

            },function(){
                $('#load').hide();
                    $('#view').text('View details');

                });     

        });     
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using callback in .load() may help you achieve exactly what you are looking for. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){       
    $('#view').toggle(function(){
        var href=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#view').text('please wait...');
        $('#load').hide().fadeIn().load(href, function(){
             $('#view').text('Hide');
        });
        return false;
    },function(){
        $('#load').hide();
        $('#view').text('View details');
    });
});     
</script>
```

Comment: no problem at all.. By the way, the toggle event handler has been deprecated as of jquery 1.8.1 & 1.9 does not support it all. You might not want to use this in your page